# MongoDB and java - cannot find Document class

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to connect Java and MongoDB. I wrote the following code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDB");
database.getCollection(database.getCollection("testC"));
```

So I have this error `The method getCollection(String) from the type MongoDatabase refers to the missing type Document`. Has anybody some idea how to fix that? I use 3.2 drivers.
Thanks in advance.
P.S. Actually when I add it via dependency in maven project it working, but when I add driver via jar it is not. How can I make it work via manually adding a jar.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which jar files are on your classpath.

If you're using the uber jar, named mongo-java-driver, then that should be sufficient as it contains the Document class.  If you're using the mongodb-driver jar, then you also need the mongodb-driver-core and bson jar files.   See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/getting-started/installation-guide/ for further details.